# Recently updated to Windows 10; Stereo Mix not recording audio

Tags: windows-10, audio-recording

When my computer was using Windows 7, I used Stereo Mix a ton for recording sound. However when I updated to Windows 10, it doesn't work anymore. I updated drivers, and from there enabled Stereo Mix again. The issue I'm encountering is that for some reason after the update, Stereo Mix doesn't want to record any sound regardless of anything I've tried. I've tried switching sound devices, making it my default microphone, my drivers are fully updated, I've attempted disabling 'Listen to this Device', etc. Nothing works in multiple programs.

Comment: Did you try this:
Settings > System > Sound > Other Sound Options > App volume and device preferences>  Input - Stereo mix

Comment: and this:
Settings > System > Sound >  Input - Stereo mix

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was: "Computer sound must go through the sound card. Using HDMI to output video and audio will bypass the sound card. Sometimes the only way to force it, is to connect any kind of speaker." (from harrymc answer)
To clarify there was a usb headphones which I used as playback device. And Stereo Mix was recording silence. Turns out  Stereo Mix only records sound which goes through same audio card Stereo Mix itself belongs to. That was a hard part to understand for me. You need to set that card as playback device to be able to record sound.
Posting this as it took several hours for me to understand that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This should work if you have done the following:

- In *Control Panel > Sound > Recording*, right click Stereo Mix and select Enable
- You may also need to right click Stereo Mix again and select Set as Default Device

Stereo Mix should now appear as an option in any recording program
such as Audacity:

[image]

There are many more factors that can still disable Stereo Mix.
Some of them are:

- In *Control Panel > Sound > Playback*, right click speakers, select
  Properties, and if you have a Level tab, then
  unmute sound and microphone adjust adjust the sound level to the highest
- The driver of the sound card may not be the latest version
- Computer sound must go through the sound card.
  Using HDMI to output video and audio will bypass the sound card.
  Sometimes the only way to force it, is to connect any kind of speaker.
- The microphone may need to be disabled
- Volume level of the sound card should be set to 100%
- The default playback device may need to be set to Digital Output
- A headset plugged-in might disable Stereo Mix
- If the sound card has the property of Acoustic Echo Cancellation, it should
  be set to Off
- Some unlisted fixes may be found in the article
  [Fix: Stereo Mix not Working](https://appuals.com/fix-stereo-mix-not-working/).

Comment: My issue is that, instead of it not appearing, it just doesn't record anything; it just records silence.